# how to login into a website using python

Tags: python

can someone help me to get a python work and login into these values? below

```
  <div class='field'>
  <label for='login'>Login</label><br/>
  <input id='login' name='login' size='16' type='text' />
</div>
<div class='field'>
  <label for='login_password'>Password</label><br/>
  <input id='login' name='password' size='16' type='password' />
</div>
<div class='field'>
  <input type='submit' value='Login' />
</div>
```

I'm getting tired of trying million times with this code

```
import sys,os,time,subprocess,threading,readline,fileinput, urllib, urllib2, cookielib
usernameInsnort = ''
passwordInsnort = ''
print 'can you pleasse insert your snort user name:'
usernameStr = raw_input(usernameInsnort)
print 'can you please insert your snort password:'
passwordStr = raw_input(passwordInsnort)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)) 
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : usernameStr, 'login' : passwordStr})
opener.open('https://www.snort.org/login', login_data)
resp = opener.open ('https://www.snort.org/downloads/2142')
print resp.read()
```

thanks

Comment: urllib2 is horrible. Consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) which has a much better+saner api.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a bit of the HTML quote from the source which is needed to quickly tell the reason why your method is not working

```
<form action="https://www.snort.org/session" 
    method="post">
    <input name="authenticity_token" 
        type="hidden" value="y4xmS1IJatlRmkFz4GT4OrBuE57cBCtHj0ka0UPg9sw=" />
    <fieldset> 
        [Snip - You already provided this bit]
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

From this HTML we can identify two issues

- The form posts to `/session` not `/login`
- <strike>There is an `authenticity_token` field to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)</strike> Does not seem to be an issue, probably because no user session has been set up yet

---

From the original Paython code you provide notice this line

```
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : usernameStr, 'login' : passwordStr})
```

In which another issue is identified

- You never encode the value of password because it is encoded to login

---

So taking all that into account we can make your code work by making a few changes

```
import sys,os,time,subprocess,threading,readline,fileinput, urllib, urllib2, cookielib
usernameInsnort = ''
passwordInsnort = ''
print 'can you pleasse insert your snort user name:'
usernameStr = raw_input(usernameInsnort)
print 'can you please insert your snort password:'
passwordStr = raw_input(passwordInsnort)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)) 

# Changed the second dictionary item to password instead of login
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : usernameStr, 'password' : passwordStr})

# Changed the URL opened to that the login form submits to
opener.open('https://www.snort.org/session', login_data)

resp = opener.open ('https://www.snort.org/downloads/2142')
print resp.read()
```